# Typescript definitions for Animated.View's style prop

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I have component whose `Props` interface extends `ViewProps` from React Native, i.e:

```
export interface Props extends ViewProps {
  // Custom props
}
```

Naturally, this extends the `style` prop. There is one caveat, I am using `Animated.View` and have style like this:

```
style={{
  opacity: animationCharacter.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1]
  }),
  transform: [
    {
      scale: animationCharacter.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [1.2, 1]
      })
    }
  ]
}}
```

I think the `interpolate` call is incompatible with style typings from `ViewProps`, but there is no `AnimatedViewProps` I can extend.

Is there a solution here or will I have to set `style: any`?

Comment: I don't think I have enough to provide an answer, but I did some research and it seems that calls to interpolate yield a `Animated.Value`. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations. See also: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12202 for work on integrating this into the core library,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there's a builtin solution. Looking at [the type definitions for React Native](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts), the Animated namespace doesn't even specify types for the Animated components, and [just leaves them as `any`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L8413-L8420):

```
/**
 * Animated variants of the basic native views. Accepts Animated.Value for
 * props and style.
 */
export const View: any;
export const Image: any;
export const Text: any;
export const ScrollView: any;
```

Even the React Native source (which uses FlowType) leaves the props to an a [plain Object type](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animated/src/createAnimatedComponent.js#L27):

```
class AnimatedComponent extends React.Component<Object> {
  …
}
```

This is probably because React Native has wrapper classes for internally handling animated [styles](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e708010d18f938e2d6b6424cfc9485d8e5dd2800/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedStyle.js) and [props](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e708010d18f938e2d6b6424cfc9485d8e5dd2800/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedProps.js) (even [transforms](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e708010d18f938e2d6b6424cfc9485d8e5dd2800/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedTransform.js)) specifically, making it a lot harder to specify types exactly due to abstraction. I think your best bet here is to use `any` since it would incredibly tedious to create your own types, and with little benefit.

Comment: I think this is the issue that keeps track of the problem: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12202

Answer (score 20):

Starting from [@types/react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-native) v0.61.9, you can use `Animated.AnimatedProps`:

For exemple for the style prop:

```js
interface Props {
  style?: Animated.AnimatedProps<StyleProp<ViewStyle>>,
}
```

Or to get all props:

```js
export interface Props extends Animated.AnimatedProps<ViewProps> {
  // Custom props
}
```

Comment: For me, using just `Animated.AnimatedProps<ViewStyle>` solved the issue.

Comment: Update: There's a typo in the answer, it should be `Animated.AnimateProps<ViewProps>` and not `Animated.AnimatedProps<ViewProps>`

Comment:  `Animated.AnimatedProps<ViewProps>['style']` worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

I've made 'kind of' type that converts any view styles into animatable styles.

```
type MaybeAnimated<T> = T | Animated.Value;
type AnimatedScalar = string | number;

type AnimatedStyles<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends AnimatedScalar
    ? MaybeAnimated<T[Key]>
    : T[Key] extends Array<infer U>
    ? Array<AnimatedStyles<U>>
    : AnimatedStyles<T[Key]>
};

type ViewAnimatedStyles = AnimatedStyles<ViewStyle>;

const test: ViewAnimatedStyles = {
  transform: [
    {
      rotateY: new Animated.Value(2),
    }
  ]
}
```

You get auto-suggestions and animated values work.

Limitation:
`Animated.Value` definition under the hood is just empty class so technically, everything will match it. So you'll be able to assign an incorrect value to it (eg plain string instead of number)

Read more about infered and conditional types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

Comment: Cool! Thanks. 

Comment: I guess this has changed now, Animated.Value now asks for a type argument

Answer (score 5):

//  import {Animated} from "react-native"

```
interface ImageComponentProps {
  height: Animated.Value;
  width: Animated.Value;
  opacity: Animated.Value;
  uri: string;
}
```

this worked for me !!

Answer (score 4):

React-Native library already exposes little helper for that:

```
import { Animated } from "react-native";

type AnimatedViewStyle = Animated.WithAnimatedValue<ViewStyle>;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me the type definition like this one:

```
 const scaleValue = new Animated.Value( 0 );
 const cardScale: Animated.Mapping = scaleValue.interpolate( {
    inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
    outputRange: [1, .95, .9],
  } );
 const transformStyle = {transform: [{scale: cardScale}]};
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  onPressIn={ () => {
    scaleValue.setValue( 0 );
    Animated.timing( scaleValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 60,
      easing: Easing.lenear
    } ).start();
   } }

   onPressOut={ () => {
    Animated.timing( scaleValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 550,
      easing: Easing.bounce,
    } ).start();
   } }
>
  <Animated.View style={ transformStyle }>
    {// some stuff}
  </Animated.View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing answers worked for my use case, so I rolled my own that seems to work:

```js
import { RecursiveArray } from "lodash";
import {
    Animated,
    Falsy,
    ImageStyle,
    RegisteredStyle,
    TextStyle,
    ViewStyle,
} from "react-native";

export type AnimatedStyleProp<T extends Style> =
    | T
    | AnimatedStyle<T>
    | RegisteredStyle<T>
    | Falsy
    | RecursiveArray<
        | T
        | AnimatedStyle<T>
        | RegisteredStyle<T>
        | Falsy >;

type AnimatedStyle<T extends Style> =
    | T
    | Animated.Value
    | Animated.AnimatedInterpolation
    | Animated.WithAnimatedObject<T>
    | Animated.WithAnimatedArray<T>;

type Style = ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle;
```

`AnimatedStyleProp<T>` is exactly the same as the definition for `StyleProp<T>`, but with the addition of `AnimatedStyle<T>`.

If you're not using `lodash`, this is the definition of `RecursiveArray<T>` (which is used in `@types/react-native` but not exported):

```js
interface RecursiveArray<T> extends Array<
    | T
    | ReadonlyArray<T>
    | RecursiveArray<T>
> {}
```