# Why can't I use StyleProp<ViewStyle> on my own component

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typescript3.0

I'm using TypeScript/Vscode for coding my React Native app. I want code completion on my custom components for style just like React Native's own `View` component does.

`style` prop `View` is defined like this:

```
style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
```

When I try it on my own component's props:

```
type MyViewProps = { style?:StyleProp<ViewStyle> }
class MyView extends Component<MyViewProps>{ ... }
```

And try to use it the way I use `style` on a regular view:

```
<MyView style={{top:-20}}/>
```

I get the following error:

```
Type '{ style: { top: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<MyViewProps, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<Pick<MyViewProps, never>> & Readonly<...>'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<MyViewProps, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<Pick<MyViewProps, never>> & Readonly<...>'.ts(2322)
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Just for clarification: the style *does* work perfectly on runtime, it's just the code completion/IntelliSense that I can't get to work)

Answer (score 9):

If you don't care about Animated views.

```js
type MyViewProps = { style?: ViewStyle };
```

And if you do care about `Animated.View`.

```js
type MaybeAnimated<T> = T | Animated.Value;
type AnimatedScalar = string | number;

type AnimatedStyle<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends AnimatedScalar
    ? MaybeAnimated<T[Key]>
    : T[Key] extends Array<infer U>
    ? Array<AnimatedStyle<U>>
    : AnimatedStyle<T[Key]>;
};
```

Use it like this.

```js
type MyViewProps = { style?: AnimatedStyle<ViewStyle> };
```

Go [upvote here too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279452/25197) as it's where I found 99% of this answer.

Comment: how to make the AnimatedStyle work with Stylesheet.create ?